# Adobe Flex: Error#1034 in trying to validate datagrid input

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, adobe, textinput, type-coercion

Trying to validate the input in my data grid, I am using a function (taken from an Adobe example).

This is how the grid goes:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="CashGrid" dataProvider="{cash}" editable="true" itemEditBeginning="allowForEdit(event)"  itemEditEnd="formatData(event);" sortableColumns="false">  
 <mx:columns>  
     <mx:DataGridColumn textAlign="left" dataField="curName" headerText="Currency" />  
     <mx:DataGridColumn textAlign="right" dataField="value" headerText="Value"  width="150">  
 </mx:columns>  
</mx:DataGrid>
```

And here is the function from the AS part

```
  public function formatData(event:DataGridEvent):void
  {
     if (event.reason == DataGridEventReason.CANCELLED)
     {
      // Do not update cell.
      return;
     }            

     var newData:String= TextInput(event.currentTarget.itemEditorInstance).text;

     // Determine if the new value is an empty String. 
     if(newData == "")
               {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        TextInput(cashGrid.itemEditorInstance).errorString=
                            "Enter a valid string.";
                        return;
               }
  }
```

Although it works in the source example, in my example, on editing said grid, an error pops up saying
`TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert mx.controls::TextInput@f093c29 to spark.components.TextInput.`

Trying to

```
import mx.controls.TextInput;
```

tells me

`Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. spark.components.TextInput.`

I guess there is some confusion with the namespaces, but I have no idea how to make this work.
Help!

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sankaranarayanan, Sorry I think I messed up the comment section somehow. allowForEdit(event) is an independent function which checks for a certain flag and prevents editing if it's true. It works fine on its own (when formatData(event) is not present). Also, I get my error even if I remove the itemEditBeginning="..." from the datagrid definition altogether, so alowForEdit() shouldn't be the cause of the problem. I can still add it if you think it could possibly help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error with the given code. It's working fine on my end. Please send me the code for `allowForEdit(event)` as well.

Which SDK version are you using?
What is the root application namespace? Please paste the entire application namespace.

Comment: Using Flash Builder 4.5   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
      width="1000" height="750">
And here is the function allowForEdit(event) 
private function allowForEdit(event:DataGridEvent) : void
 {
  if( event.dataField == "value" ) {
                var item:Object = ((event.currentTarget as DataGrid).dataProvider as ArrayCollection)[event.rowIndex];
  if( flagIsFinal == 1 ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     }
    }
 }

Comment: Hi Friend thanks for reply. I found solution for your problem.Just check the textinput class package in script location whether it is spark.components.textinput or mx.controls.textinput if it is mx.controls then change that to spark ones if it is spark then change to mx one and let me know the results

Comment: import mx.controls.TextInput;  

Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously. spark.components.TextInput.

Delete import spark.components.TextInput line from script block

Comment: Thanks for replying, Sankar. My current program, which functions fine except for this bit, has no textinput import at all. Adding import spark.components.TextInput gives the same Runtime Error#1034. Adding import mx.controls. TextInput gives the compile time error "Can not resolve...". Is the spark import coming in automatically somehow? I currently include DataGrid, Alert and dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn from mx.controls; ArrayCollection from mx.collections; and some mx.events. Any other ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Solved!!
Thanks Sankar, when you said you couldn't reproduce the error, I got a hint.
Without specifically importing TextInput, I was using s:TextInput elsewhere in the code.
When unqualified, TextInput must have been causing confusion. I just made the namespace explicit, as below, and things worked.
            
var newData:String=mx.controls.TextInput(event.currentTarget.itemEditorInstance).text;

Phew!

Thanks again.